# How unserialize JSONP

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonp

I use JSON and unserialized services as follows:

```
NSString *filtered = [restConnection stringData];
encodData = [filtered dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:encodData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"json 1: %@", json);
```

but now a new client uses JSONP, or JSON with padding services and not serialize it,can you help me

this is an string JSON standard:

```
NSString *  @"[{\"CodigoRTA\":\"91\",\"MensajeRTA\":\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\",\"Respuesta\":\"\"}]"

NSString *  @"\[{\\\"CodigoRTA\\\":\\\"91\\\",\\\"MensajeRTA\\\":\\\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\\\",\\\"Respuesta\\\":\\\"\\\"}]\""
```

And this is JSONP example:

```
NSString *  @"\"[{\\\"CodigoRTA\\\":\\\"91\\\",\\\"MensajeRTA\\\":\\\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\\\",\\\"Respuesta\\\":\\\"\\\"}]\""
```

Comment: That's a new one on me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: (But I think you're trying to DEserialize it, not serialize it.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get JSONP from JSON:

```
NSString *jsonp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@(%@)", callbackName, json];
```

(`callbackName` is usually either the value of the `callback` parameter, or `@"callback"`).

If you need to **de**serialize JSONP, just strip off the first `(` and everything before it, and last `)`, and you get JSON; easy to do with a regular expression.

**EDIT:** Also, I am not sure what I would call this, but it is not JSON:

```
@"[{\\"CodigoRTA\\":\\"91\\",\\"MensajeRTA\\":\\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\\",\\"Respuesta\\":\\"\\"}]\""
```

Nor is this JSONP (but at least I can say what it is: JSON-encoded JSON):

```
@"\"[{\\"CodigoRTA\\":\\"91\\",\\"MensajeRTA\\":\\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\\",\\"Respuesta\\":\\"\\"}]\""
```

The JSONP that corresponds to your first (correct) JSON is this:

```
@"callback([{\"CodigoRTA\":\"91\",\"MensajeRTA\":\"Error de Inicio de sesión: Error con la validación de seguridad de la clave para el inicio de sesión\",\"Respuesta\":\"\"}])"
```

**EDIT2:** JSONP to JSON should be something like this (I am not good at ObjC, so you might need to debug it):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\((.*)"
                                              options: NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                              error:NULL];

NSTextCheckingResult *searchResult =
    [regex firstMatchInString:jsonp
                      options:0
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonp length])];

NSString *json = [json substringWithRange:searchResult.range];
```

Comment: I need convert JSONP on JSON